# Como selecionar um valor específico em uma Lista em C#

Tags: c#, .net, arraylist

```
namespace Faturamento
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double menorValor = 0, dia_menor = 0, maiorValor = 0, dia_maior = 0;


            List<dados> diaMes = new List<dados>()
            {
                new dados() {dia = 1, valor = 22174.1664},
                new dados() {dia = 2, valor = 24537.6698},
                new dados() {dia = 3, valor = 26139.6134},
                new dados() {dia = 4, valor = 0.0},
                new dados() {dia = 5, valor = 0.0},
                new dados() {dia = 6, valor = 26742.6612},
                new dados() {dia = 7, valor = 0.0},
                new dados() {dia = 8, valor = 42889.2258},
                new dados() {dia = 9, valor = 46251.174},
                new dados() {dia = 10, valor = 11191.4722},
                new dados() {dia = 11, valor = 0.0},
                new dados() {dia = 12, valor = 0.0},
                new dados() {dia = 13, valor = 3847.4823},
                new dados() {dia = 14, valor = 373.7838},
                new dados() {dia = 15, valor = 2659.7563},
                new dados() {dia = 16, valor = 48924.2448},
                new dados() {dia = 17, valor = 18419.2614},
                new dados() {dia = 18, valor = 0.0},
                new dados() {dia = 19, valor = 0.0},
                new dados() {dia = 20, valor = 35240.1826},
                new dados() {dia = 21, valor = 43829.1667},
                new dados() {dia = 22, valor = 18235.6852},
                new dados() {dia = 23, valor = 4355.0662},
                new dados() {dia = 24, valor = 13327.1025},
                new dados() {dia = 25, valor = 0.0},
                new dados() {dia = 26, valor = 0.0},
                new dados() {dia = 27, valor = 25681.8318},
                new dados() {dia = 28, valor = 1718.1221},
                new dados() {dia = 29, valor = 13220.495},
                new dados() {dia = 30, valor = 8414.61},
            };
            var diaMesOrdenado = from a in diaMes
                                 orderby a.valor, a.dia
                                 select new { a.dia, a.valor };

            foreach (var dados in diaMesOrdenado)
            {
                if (dados.valor == 0)
                {
                    
                }
            }

            
            foreach (var dados in diaMesOrdenado)
            {
              if (dados.valor < menorValor || menorValor == null)
                 {
                    var soma = 0;
                    soma += dados.valor;
                 }
         
            Console.WriteLine($"{dados.dia} - {dados.valor}");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();


    }
```

Qual seria a forma mais eficiente de selecionar o maior e o menor valor da lista e somar todos os valores para ter uma média?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Sabendo que você ordenou por valor do menor pro maior, podemos pegar a partir do método `FirstOrDefault()` e `LastOrDefault()` do Linq. Com isso pegaremos o primeiro e último elemento, sabendo as propriedades dia e valor o mesmo.
Para pegar a soma e a média, você pode usar os métodos `sum(i => i.valor)` e `average(i => i.valor)` respectivamente.

Um exemplo de código abaixo:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double menorValor = 0, maiorValor = 0, soma = 0, media = 0;
        int dia_menor = 0, dia_maior = 0;


        List<dados> diaMes = new List<dados>()
        {
            new dados() {dia = 1, valor = 22174.1664},
            new dados() {dia = 2, valor = 24537.6698},
            new dados() {dia = 3, valor = 26139.6134},
            new dados() {dia = 4, valor = 0.0},
            new dados() {dia = 5, valor = 0.0},
            new dados() {dia = 6, valor = 26742.6612},
            new dados() {dia = 7, valor = 0.0},
            new dados() {dia = 8, valor = 42889.2258},
            new dados() {dia = 9, valor = 46251.174},
            new dados() {dia = 10, valor = 11191.4722},
            new dados() {dia = 11, valor = 0.0},
            new dados() {dia = 12, valor = 0.0},
            new dados() {dia = 13, valor = 3847.4823},
            new dados() {dia = 14, valor = 373.7838},
            new dados() {dia = 15, valor = 2659.7563},
            new dados() {dia = 16, valor = 48924.2448},
            new dados() {dia = 17, valor = 18419.2614},
            new dados() {dia = 18, valor = 0.0},
            new dados() {dia = 19, valor = 0.0},
            new dados() {dia = 20, valor = 35240.1826},
            new dados() {dia = 21, valor = 43829.1667},
            new dados() {dia = 22, valor = 18235.6852},
            new dados() {dia = 23, valor = 4355.0662},
            new dados() {dia = 24, valor = 13327.1025},
            new dados() {dia = 25, valor = 0.0},
            new dados() {dia = 26, valor = 0.0},
            new dados() {dia = 27, valor = 25681.8318},
            new dados() {dia = 28, valor = 1718.1221},
            new dados() {dia = 29, valor = 13220.495},
            new dados() {dia = 30, valor = 8414.61},
        };
        
        var diaMesOrdenado = from a in diaMes
                                orderby a.valor, a.dia
                                select new { a.dia, a.valor };
        
        var first = diaMesOrdenado.FirstOrDefault();
        menorValor = first.valor;
        dia_menor = first.dia;
    
        var last = diaMesOrdenado.LastOrDefault();
        maiorValor = last.valor;
        dia_maior = last.dia;
    
        soma = diaMesOrdenado.Sum(i => i.valor);
        media = diaMesOrdenado.Average(i => i.valor);
    
    
        Console.WriteLine(dia_menor);
        Console.WriteLine(dia_maior);
        Console.WriteLine(menorValor);
        Console.WriteLine(maiorValor);
        Console.WriteLine(soma);
        Console.WriteLine(media);
            
        
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Vi que é possível ter vários dias com o mesmo valor, recomendo, caso queira a coleção de dias que tiveram o menor/maior preço, tu pegue o menor/maior valor pelos métodos `Min()` e `Max()` respectivamente após um `Select(i => i.valor)`, e a partir desses valores fazer um filtro usando `Where(i => i.valor == menorValor).Select(i => i.dia)`, por exemplo, assim pegando os dias que tiveram o menor valor. Para o maior valor é a mesma coisa usando o maiorValor encontrado.
Exemplo do código:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double menorValor = 0, maiorValor = 0, soma = 0, media = 0;


        List<dados> diaMes = new List<dados>()
        {
            new dados() {dia = 1, valor = 22174.1664},
            new dados() {dia = 2, valor = 24537.6698},
            new dados() {dia = 3, valor = 26139.6134},
            new dados() {dia = 4, valor = 0.0},
            new dados() {dia = 5, valor = 0.0},
            new dados() {dia = 6, valor = 26742.6612},
            new dados() {dia = 7, valor = 0.0},
            new dados() {dia = 8, valor = 42889.2258},
            new dados() {dia = 9, valor = 46251.174},
            new dados() {dia = 10, valor = 11191.4722},
            new dados() {dia = 11, valor = 0.0},
            new dados() {dia = 12, valor = 0.0},
            new dados() {dia = 13, valor = 3847.4823},
            new dados() {dia = 14, valor = 373.7838},
            new dados() {dia = 15, valor = 2659.7563},
            new dados() {dia = 16, valor = 48924.2448},
            new dados() {dia = 17, valor = 18419.2614},
            new dados() {dia = 18, valor = 0.0},
            new dados() {dia = 19, valor = 0.0},
            new dados() {dia = 20, valor = 35240.1826},
            new dados() {dia = 21, valor = 43829.1667},
            new dados() {dia = 22, valor = 18235.6852},
            new dados() {dia = 23, valor = 4355.0662},
            new dados() {dia = 24, valor = 13327.1025},
            new dados() {dia = 25, valor = 0.0},
            new dados() {dia = 26, valor = 0.0},
            new dados() {dia = 27, valor = 25681.8318},
            new dados() {dia = 28, valor = 1718.1221},
            new dados() {dia = 29, valor = 13220.495},
            new dados() {dia = 30, valor = 8414.61},
        };
                    
        menorValor = diaMes.Select(i => i.valor).Min();
    
        maiorValor = diaMes.Select(i => i.valor).Max();
    
        soma = diaMes.Sum(i => i.valor);
        media = diaMes.Average(i => i.valor);
        
        Console.WriteLine("menor valor: " + menorValor);
        Console.WriteLine("maior valor: " + maiorValor);
        Console.WriteLine("soma: " + soma);
        Console.WriteLine("media: " + media);
        
        var menoresDias = diaMes.Where(i => i.valor == menorValor).Select(i => i.dia);
        Console.Write("Menores dias: ");    
        foreach(int dia in menoresDias){
                Console.Write(dia + " ");
            };
        var maioresDias = diaMes.Where(i => i.valor == maiorValor).Select(i => i.dia);
        Console.Write("Maiores dias: ");
            foreach(int dia in maioresDias){
                Console.Write(dia + " ");
            };
        
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Repare que dessa segunda forma não há a necessidade de ordernação da sua coleção. Mas vai do seu gosto também, as buscas podem ser mais performáticas com uma lista ordenada.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta o seguinte:

```
// Vai ordenar decrescentemente pelo maior dia
var resultado = diaMes.OrderByDescending(x => x.dia).FirstOrDefault();

// Vai ordenar decrescentemente pelo maior valor
var resultado2 = diaMes.OrderByDescending(x => x.valor).FirstOrDefault();
```

O inverso também é possível, vamos lá...

```
// Vai ordenar decrescentemente pelo maior dia
var resultado = diaMes.OrderBy(x => x.dia).FirstOrDefault();

// Vai ordenar decrescentemente pelo maior valor
var resultado2 = diaMes.OrderBy(x => x.valor).FirstOrDefault();
```

Em ambas as situações, pegamos apenas um único registro.

Para somar e tirar a média, tente o seguinte:

```
var resultadoSoma = diaMes.Sum(x => x.valor);
var media = resultadoSoma / diaMes.Count();
```